# Rails often print html tags as text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

Details first:

- Rails ver 5
- using slim template
- deployed on heroku

Since upgrading to rails 5, my app sometimes print out html tags as text.

[image]

As seen above, the code in the layout prints out just fine. But codes that is yielded in the layout is wrong.

The code yielded is cached, does this affect the rendering?

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

EDIT:

My layout code
[image]

The Index View code
[image]

The rendered html (sometimes it is escaped, so not always, sometimes it works)
[image]

Thank you

Comment: can you show us the view code ? also the image looks like a mobile phone, is this a native app or are you browsing the site from the browser ?

Comment: I am browsing the site from mobile browser. I will post the view code as soon as I get hands on a pc

Answer (score 0):

Found it, it was the caches_action acting up, not really sure why it caused it.

[image]

Comment: Please add your code as real code and not as image.

Comment: Posting pictures instead of code is not being a good SO community member.  Also, please mark the answer as chosen so this is not listed as an unanswered question.